# Adding elements dynamically to DOM in $(document).ready(function(){}); adds the elements but they arent visible. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dom, dom-manipulation

I am adding two collapsibles of jquery-mobile in $(document).ready(function(){ });

It looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var l_freeCollabsible=fCreateCollapsible("Free", "Free Content");
     var l_bestSellCollabsible=fCreateCollapsible("Best Sellers", "Best Selling Content");

     var l_frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

     l_frag.appendChild(l_freeCollabsible);
     l_frag.appendChild(l_bestSellCollabsible);

     document.body.appendChild(l_frag);
});
```

fCreateCollapsible() looks like this

```
 function fCreateCollapsible(heading,content){
    var l_collapsible = fDomCrElemTypeTheme("div","collapsible","b","b");
    l_collapsible.setAttribute("data-iconpos","right");
    var l_heading = fDomCrElemText("h4",heading);
    var l_content = fDomCrElemText("span",content);

    apc(l_collapsible,l_heading);
    apc(l_collapsible,l_content);

    return l_collapsible;
 }
```

this function creates the following structure

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b" data-iconpos="right">
   <h4>Heading</h4>
    <span>
       Content
   </span>
</div>
```

My Problem is that after Dom ready is called the elements are created as I want, but they are hidden.

I tried creating a function, putting the element creation code in it and calling the function from inside the body. It works perfectly.

Is there any way to apply jquery styles in the ready function? I want to create all the elements dynamically with an empty pair of body tags. I am trying to create a simple mobile application with jqm+phonegap

am using jquery-mobile-1.3.2 and jquery-1.9.1.

Comment: use `$('[data-role=collapsible]').trigger('create')` after appending the items.

Comment: generally you don't use documentready with jQM, instead you use pageinit or pagecreate.

Comment: Here is how it looks like when it works by creating a function and calling it in the body  [how it looks](http://i.imgur.com/uGK4jKM.png?1)

Comment: @KevinB thanks, I created a page div, used pageinit, and then used 

    `$('[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible().trigger("create");`

to create all the collapsibles